# Submit Data in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am trying to submit my data using mongoose in my NEXT app, I am able to fetch data using getServerSideProps like

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const data = await shop.findOne({ shopName: "testing" });

  return {
    props: {
      dbData: JSON.stringify(data),
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

Now I want to put some data in my mongoDb is there any method that will run after my button click and renders server side code just like getServerSideProps in which i can run my mongoose query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way in your api controller

```
const handler = nextConnect();

//Shop Schema
const Shop = mongoose.model('Shop',{ 
    shopName: String,
    id: String  
});

//Post request handeler
handler.post(async (req, res) => {
  var shop = new Shop({ 
        shopName: req.body.name, 
        id:req.body.id 
   }) 
  let data = await shop.save();
  res.json({message: 'ok'});
})
```

Comment: just read this https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-connect